# Killing kubectl exec command from master node doesn't kill the command running inside pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I ran `kubectl exec -it pod_XXXX -- top` command from my master node. Then killed the `kubectl exec` process by `sudo kill -9 <pid_of_kubectl>` command from another terminal.

```
 kubectl exec -it pod_XXXX -- top
 sudo kill -9 <pid_of_kubectl_exec_command>
```

Inside POD the `top` command keeps running.This issue is not seen when i press `crtl+c` to terminate the `kubectl exec`. Is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By running **kubectl exec -it** you're connecting/streaming your terminal to the pod terminal so that if you type anything to your terminal, streams to the pod terminal. That's why when you run **kubectl exec -it pod_XXXX -- top** on your terminal, it worked as expected. Remember, the POD's termial is running the **top** interface, not yours.

So, when you type **sudo kill -9 pid_of_kubectl_exec_command**, it kills the connection between your terminal and the POD's terminal. So, the process inside the POD's terminal keeps running.

When you press **ctrl+c** from your terminal, it streams **ctrl+c** to the POD terminal, that's why the **top** terminates instantly.